# scrapy with selenium chromedriver seems much slower now

Tags: selenium, scrapy, selenium-chromedriver

i have been downloading files from a UK government website (the government makes them available to be downloaded) using scrapy and selenium.  This was all working fine when i last did this at the end of April.

the webpage has a list of xml files that i use scrapy to get the urls and then selenium to open them and scrapy to get the contents.

However, more recently it has become very slow.  the Chrome page that the chromedriver.exe opens up starts well, files are opened and the xml contents displayed one after another and i can scrape the XML data but after a few files are accessed it gets very slow. the Chrome page takes a long time to open a file and often times out?

i have updated the Chrimedriver to 83 given the update in Chrome recently.

does anyone have any ideas?

my code is below:

```
import scrapy

from urllib.parse import urljoin
from foodstandardsagency.items import FoodstandardsagencyItem
from selenium import webdriver

from scrapy.http import TextResponse


class foodstandardsagencySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "foodstandardsagency"
    allowed_domains = ["ratings.food.gov.uk"]
    start_urls = ["http://ratings.food.gov.uk/open-data/en-GB"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.xpath('//tr/td/div/a[text()[contains(.,"English")]]/@href'):
            url = urljoin('http://ratings.food.gov.uk/',href.extract())
            print(url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/andrew/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
        except:
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/andre/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")


    def parse_dir_contents(self, response):  
        self.driver.get(response.url)

        response1 = TextResponse(url=response.url, body=self.driver.page_source, encoding='utf-8')

        for sel in response1.xpath('//*[@id="folder2"]/div[@class="opened"]/div[@class="folder"]/div[@class="opened"]'):
            businessname = sel.xpath('.//span[text()[contains(.,"<BusinessName")]]/../span[2]/text()').extract()
            postcode = sel.xpath('.//span[text()[contains(.,"<PostCode")]]/../span[2]/text()').extract()
            businesstype = sel.xpath('.//span[text()[contains(.,"<BusinessType") and not(contains(., "<BusinessTypeID"))]]/../span[2]/text()').extract()
            businesstypeID = sel.xpath('.//span[text()[contains(.,"<BusinessTypeID")]]/../span[2]/text()').extract()
            ratingvalue = sel.xpath('.//span[text()[contains(.,"<RatingValue")]]/../span[2]/text()').extract()
            ratingdate = sel.xpath('.//span[text()[contains(.,"<RatingDate")]]/../span[2]/text()').extract()
            item = FoodstandardsagencyItem()
            item['businessname'] = businessname
            item['postcode'] = postcode
            item['businesstype'] = businesstype
            item['businesstypeID'] = businesstypeID
            item['ratingvalue'] = ratingvalue
            item['ratingdate'] = ratingdate
            yield item
```

Answer (score 0):

So, in the end i decided to add code to close and restart chromedriver after each xml file is opened, and i set the concurrent openings to 1 (from the default 16) in settings.

the code i added was:

```
    self.driver.close()
    try:
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/andrew/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
    except:
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/andre/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
```

in settings the code added was:

```
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1
```

not great for memory usage but it was the best i could come up with to make it work.

full code therefore is:

```
import scrapy

from urllib.parse import urljoin
from foodstandardsagency.items import FoodstandardsagencyItem
from selenium import webdriver

from scrapy.http import TextResponse


class foodstandardsagencySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "foodstandardsagency"
    allowed_domains = ["ratings.food.gov.uk"]
    start_urls = ["http://ratings.food.gov.uk/open-data/en-GB"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.xpath('//tr/td/div/a[text()[contains(.,"English")]]/@href'):
            url = urljoin('http://ratings.food.gov.uk/',href.extract())
            print(url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/andrew/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
        except:
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/andre/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")

    def parse_dir_contents(self, response):  
        self.driver.get(response.url)

        response1 = TextResponse(url=response.url, body=self.driver.page_source, encoding='utf-8')
        for sel in response1.xpath('//*[@id="folder2"]/div[@class="opened"]/div[@class="folder"]/div[@class="opened"]'):
            businessname = sel.xpath('.//span[text()[contains(.,"<BusinessName")]]/../span[2]/text()').extract()
            postcode = sel.xpath('.//span[text()[contains(.,"<PostCode")]]/../span[2]/text()').extract()
            businesstype = sel.xpath('.//span[text()[contains(.,"<BusinessType") and not(contains(., "<BusinessTypeID"))]]/../span[2]/text()').extract()
            businesstypeID = sel.xpath('.//span[text()[contains(.,"<BusinessTypeID")]]/../span[2]/text()').extract()
            ratingvalue = sel.xpath('.//span[text()[contains(.,"<RatingValue")]]/../span[2]/text()').extract()
            ratingdate = sel.xpath('.//span[text()[contains(.,"<RatingDate")]]/../span[2]/text()').extract()
            item = FoodstandardsagencyItem()
            item['businessname'] = businessname
            item['postcode'] = postcode
            item['businesstype'] = businesstype
            item['businesstypeID'] = businesstypeID
            item['ratingvalue'] = ratingvalue
            item['ratingdate'] = ratingdate
            yield item

        self.driver.close()
        try:
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/andrew/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
        except:
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/andre/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
```